# How to format and query a PostgreSQL JSON into n column rows in sql

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I would like to use a json and be able to display it into three column rows as follow.

```
scores median sigma
------ ------ -----
BF2D   0.5    0.67
BF2DSL 0.6    0.89
```

First, I have a hard time to format it.
Second, what would be the format suitable so that I can display it into three column rows. Have a feeling that I should use array representation?
The json_to_record(json) function seems interesting for my usecase, but i need help.

```
SELECT * from json_to_record('{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": [{"median": 0.5}, {"sigma": 0.67}], "BF2DSL": [{"median": 0.6}, {"sigma": 0.89}]}'::JSON) as x(median FLOAT, sigma FLOAT);

 median | sigma
--------+--------
 (NULL) | (NULL)

Not what i am looking for
```

I tried to use nested arrays, but unable to format it into a json

```
SELECT '{"version": "1.0", "scores": [{ "BF2D": [{"median": 0.5}, {"sigma": 0.67}] }, { "BF2DSL": [{"median": 0.6}, {"sigma": 0.89}] }]'::JSON;
```

Comment: I would not use the arrays when defining the data.. I'd use something like

{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"median": 0.5, "sigma": 0.67} , "BF2DSL": {"median": 0.6, "sigma": 0.89}}

Then use json notation to get the correct fields in the select.

Comment: @JoeLove I tried, but BF2D, BF2DSF, etc keys are not known in advance. They are score values.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

We can retreive the base level keys as follow:

```
SELECT * FROM json_object_keys('{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"avg": 0.5, "max": 99}, "BF2DSL": {"avg": 0.9, "max": 67}}'::JSON) scores WHERE scores<>'version';
 scores
--------
 BF2D
 BF2DSL
```

We can get the key/values for a specific base level key, e.g., for BF2D as follow

```
SELECT * FROM json_each('{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"avg": 0.5, "max": 99}, "BF2DSL": {"avg": 0.9, "max": 67}}'::JSON->'BF2D');
 KEY | value
-----+-------
 avg | 0.5
 max | 99
```

But, cannot use the above two queries to get 3 column rows

```
SELECT scores, json_each('{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"avg": 0.5, "max": 99}, "BF2DSL": {"avg": 0.9, "max": 67}}'::JSON->scores)
FROM (SELECT * FROM json_object_keys('{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"avg": 0.5, "max": 99}, "BF2DSL": {"avg": 0.9, "max": 67}}'::JSON) scores WHERE scores<>'version') t;
 scores | json_each
--------+-----------
 BF2D   | (avg,0.5)
 BF2D   | (max,99)
 BF2DSL | (avg,0.9)
 BF2DSL | (max,67)
```

Finally, we can display the result into separate columns as follow

```
WITH p AS
  (SELECT '{"version": "1.0", "BF2D": {"avg": 0.5, "max": 99, "sigma": 0.1}, "BF2DSL": {"avg": 0.9, "max": 67}}'::JSON AS jval),
t AS
  (SELECT jval,json_object_keys(jval) cod FROM p),
scores AS
  (SELECT * FROM t WHERE cod<>'version')
SELECT cod,t.* FROM scores,json_each(jval->cod) t;

  cod   |  key  | value
--------+-------+-------
 BF2D   | avg   | 0.5
 BF2D   | max   | 99
 BF2D   | sigma | 0.1
 BF2DSL | avg   | 0.9
 BF2DSL | max   | 67
```